# Symfony 4 TwigFunction does not get registered

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am writing a Twig function in Symfony 4 but I cannot get it to work...

> The extension class

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Utils\XXX;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class XXXExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    /**
     * @return array|TwigFunction|TwigFunction[]
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return new TwigFunction('showControllerName', [$this, 'showControllerName']);
    }


    public function showControllerName($sControllerPath)
    {
        return XXX::getControllerName($sControllerPath);
    }
}
```

I have **autowire** set to **true** in **services.yaml** but just in case i tried with this also:

```
    App\Twig\XXXExtension:
        public: true
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

> usage in html.twig

```
{% set controllerName = showControllerName(app.request.get('_controller')) %}
```

and the response i get after this is:

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Unknown "showControllerName" function.
```

Comment: bin/console debug:twig will determine if the function was registered.  You might try wrapping your TwigFunction instance in an array like the docs show but it should not make a difference.

Comment: @Cerad seems that it has to be an array otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Yep.  I was going based on the type hints in your posted code.  Bit surprised that your IDE did not flag it.  The ExtensionInterface clearly show returning an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an array of functions, you are only returning one.

```
    ...
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('showControllerName', [$this, 'showControllerName']),
        ];
    }
    ...
```